# Random pop from dict, serving values, not keys

Tags: python, dictionary, random, key

```
item = word_bank.pop(random.choice(list(word_bank.keys()))) 
print(list(word_bank.keys()))
print("The Word is: ", item)
print("=" * 25)
a = input("Do You Know It? (y/n):\t")
answer = word_bank[item]
```

The `item` variable above is returning values instead of keys from my `word_bank` dictionary. I printed my list of keys to try and debug the problem and no values exist, which makes me think the problem exists with the `pop` method or the `random.choice` method. I looked into both the documentation for these and found nothing that would point out the issue.

I think it has something to do with `random.choices` returning an index to a key and then the `pop` method returning the corresponding value to that key as item. However, when I reverse the roles and use `values()` in place of `keys()` I get a key error and cannot find a working solution to the problem.

Comment: *...no values exist*, do you know what `dict.pop` does?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Yes, if you pass a key to the `.pop` method, it *pops* the corresponding value...

Answer (score 0):

*word_bank.keys()* obviously returns keys, if any. *word_bank.pop* will return value of the given key. So, *item* will contain a value from word_bank. *However, when I reverse the roles and use values() in place of keys() I get a key error*, this is because you are trying to search for keys using values. A dictionary can directly be index only by key and not by value.
Check this:

```
word_bank = {'one':1,'two':2,'three':3}
item = word_bank.pop(random.choice(list(word_bank.keys())))
print(list(word_bank.keys()))
print("The Word is: ", item)
print("=" * 25)
a = input("Do You Know It? (y/n):\t")
answer = item
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word_bank = {'hello':'goodbye','yes':'no'}    

            item = random.choice(list(word_bank.items()))
              key = item[0]
              value = item[1]
              print("The Word is: ", key)
              print("=" * 25)
              a = input("Do You Know It? (y/n):\t")
              answer = value
            if a.lower() == "y":
                  print()
                  print("Answer:\t", answer)
                  score += 1
                  del word_bank[key]           #remove from dict 
                  print()
            elif a.lower() == "n":
                  print()
                  print("Answer:\t", answer)
                  del word_bank[key]            #remove from dict
                  print()
```

I came up with this solution, but It doesn't seem very efficient, could anyone provide a way to destructively iterate through my dictionary that uses less line or provides more readability? My intuition says pop, but that only works with keys and not values, I need to remove and return a key to the user then show them the value. The above example works, but seems bulky.

Comment: So you are giving someone a point if they claim to know the answer even without checking the answer?

Comment: the program is for my use only, I am running through a dictionary of words in a different language, the keys being the foreign language and the values being English definitions. It is for my use only, so checking a response really is not an issue at this time.

Comment: why destructively? are you only answering a portion and doing something with the rest?

Comment: no particular reason except, i just do not want to receive duplicates when cycling through my random.choice of words. I suppose I could make it a loop, would that be better?

Answer (score 0):

Randomly pick a key and then `pop()` the answer:

```
import random

word_bank = {'hello':'goodbye','yes':'no'}
score = 0
item = random.choice(list(word_bank.keys()))
answer = word_bank.pop(item)
print("The Word is: ", item)
print("=" * 25)
a = input("Do You Know It? (y/n):\t")
if a.lower() == "y": score += 1
print()
print("Answer:\t", answer)
```

The above code mutates the dictionary at each stage. What if e.g. you want to run the quiz again? I don't like destroying information without reason. Here is a non-destructive version of a whole test which shuffles the keys, hence giving different orders on different runs (note that I dispensed with the variable `answer` since I only needed the value in one line of code):

```
import random

word_bank = {'hello':'goodbye','yes':'no'}
score = 0
questions = list(word_bank.keys())
random.shuffle(questions)
for item in questions:
    print("The Word is: ", item)
    print("=" * 25)
    a = input("Do You Know It? (y/n):\t")
    if a.lower() == "y": score += 1
    print()
    print("Answer:\t", word_bank[item])

print("Final score =",score)
```